# Android studio popup image buttons

Tags: java, android, popup

I'm making same App in Android studio, and i need an image popup buttons insted a text buttons. When level is failed or finish, that popup is showing. I have this code for text buttons, but how to change to insert some picture insted a text?

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Level_1.this);
            final CharSequence[] levelOptions = {"Restart", "Next level"};
            builder.setTitle("CORRECT!").setItems(levelOptions , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                    Log.d("Restart", levelOptions[which].toString());
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the alert dialog button

`Button positive= alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);`

Set the drawable image

`positive.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(this.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.pos), null, null, null);`